# While registering for API key and secret I have selected without callback URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, imgur

[image]

[imgur]

Now I am getting error in POSTMAN for:

> "error":"redirect_uri_mismatch"

Is there any way if I can change option and select with callback URL?

Or is there any way I can move ahead without callback URL

I want to generate Oayth Token for Same API

Comment: I have updated callback URL now getting error "429 Too many request"
Could you please guide me through this

Comment: I have the same issue and all the "solutions" I've read here are out of date.